# Interpret string as integer into standard Output

Tags: linux, bash, conversion

I am looking for way to convert dec number into a binary representation of a basic datatype like int8, uint8, float etc.

For example:

```
echo "123" | functionTo int8 | hexdump -C
```

Result should be "7B"

Another example

```
echo "123" | functionTo uint16 | hexdump -C
```

Result should be "007B".

Comment: Humm, the sample output you provided in hexadecimal, not binary.

Comment: functionTo uint16 creates a binary output to the standard output, hexdump converts the stdin (which is binary) into a hex representation.